# Powershell script to create scheduled Task with argument

Tags: powershell, scheduled-task, task-scheduler

i have this Script which is checking if a named service is running. In the actual case its checking for "RSCDsvc" service.

```
if(!(Get-ScheduledTask | Where-Object {$_.TaskName -like "restart_RSCDsvc" })){
New-Item -Path C:\Admin\scripts -Name check-service.cmd -Force -ItemType "file" -Value '
@ECHO OFF
SET SvcName=%~1

SC QUERYEX "%SvcName%" | FIND "STATE" | FIND /v "RUNNING" > NUL && (
ECHO %SvcName% is not running
ECHO START %SvcName%

NET START "%SvcName%" > NUL || (
ECHO "%SvcName%" wont start
EXIT /B 1
)
ECHO "%SvcName%" is started
EXIT /B 0
) || (
ECHO "%SvcName%" is running
EXIT /B 0
)
'
$dt= ([DateTime]::Now)
$timespan = $dt.AddYears(33) -$dt;
$principal = New-ScheduledTaskPrincipal -UserID "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM" -LogonType ServiceAccount -RunLevel Highest
$Action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute C:\Admin\scripts\check-service.cmd -Argument "RSCDsvc"
$Trigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Once -At (Get-Date).Date -RandomDelay (New-TimeSpan -Minutes 5) -RepetitionDuration $timespan -RepetitionInterval (New-TimeSpan -Minutes 10)
$Task = New-ScheduledTask -Action $Action -Trigger $Trigger -Settings ($Stset = New-ScheduledTaskSettingsSet -ExecutionTimeLimit (New-TimeSpan -Minutes 3)) -Principal $principal
$Task | Register-ScheduledTask -TaskName ‘restart_RSCDsvc’
}
```

Now my question would be if i can work with more arguments so i dont have to enter the specific Service name so often in the script. Now i have to set it at 3 different points

`if(!(Get-ScheduledTask | Where-Object {$_.TaskName -like "restart_RSCDsvc" }))`

`$Action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute C:\Admin\scripts\check-service.cmd -Argument "RSCDsvc"`

`$Task | Register-ScheduledTask -TaskName ‘restart_RSCDsvc’`

Like ive said my goal would be to have something like "$Servicename = RSCDSVC" and then its set for this three lines. I have tried it already but im already proud i got this script finish as im not very good in scripting :(

Answer (score 0):

You can just replace all instances of RSCDSVC with the variable name just like you theorized

```
$Servicename = "RSCDSVC"
if(!(Get-ScheduledTask | Where-Object {$_.TaskName -like "restart_$Servicename" })){
New-Item -Path C:\Admin\scripts -Name check-service.cmd -Force -ItemType "file" -Value '
@ECHO OFF
SET SvcName=%~1

SC QUERYEX "%SvcName%" | FIND "STATE" | FIND /v "RUNNING" > NUL && (
ECHO %SvcName% is not running
ECHO START %SvcName%

NET START "%SvcName%" > NUL || (
ECHO "%SvcName%" wont start
EXIT /B 1
)
ECHO "%SvcName%" is started
EXIT /B 0
) || (
ECHO "%SvcName%" is running
EXIT /B 0
)
'
$dt= ([DateTime]::Now)
$timespan = $dt.AddYears(33) -$dt;
$principal = New-ScheduledTaskPrincipal -UserID "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM" -LogonType ServiceAccount -RunLevel Highest
$Action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute C:\Admin\scripts\check-service.cmd -Argument "$Servicename"
$Trigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Once -At (Get-Date).Date -RandomDelay (New-TimeSpan -Minutes 5) -RepetitionDuration $timespan -RepetitionInterval (New-TimeSpan -Minutes 10)
$Task = New-ScheduledTask -Action $Action -Trigger $Trigger -Settings ($Stset = New-ScheduledTaskSettingsSet -ExecutionTimeLimit (New-TimeSpan -Minutes 3)) -Principal $principal
$Task | Register-ScheduledTask -TaskName "restart_$Servicename"
}
```